# WebService timeout

Tags: web-services

I have a problem with deploying my web service in our Web server. In my
development machine (inside of our LAN), everything works fine. When I move
the application into our Web server (public addressed), I always get the
timeout exception. while i connecting the web service through my web  browser it works fine with no issues, but through application am getting  the timeout error. My app connects to our database server (inside of our LAN) to get statistical data in form of datasets. can i know the issue about this point.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely a firewall/port forwarding issue.

Did I understand you correctly: Your client application connects to the database server directly?

You should check which port you are using to connect to the database server.
Then check if the web server has an active firewall and if so, configure it properly to accept connections on that port.

You can always easily check if a port is open and reachable by using telnet:

On the command line type telnet MY_IP MY_PORT.
If a connection can be established the port is open.